How to protect a token-key?
I made a node server where i get the encrypted token for my map services, in my flutter app i decrypt it .
The thing is i wanted to protect my token from beeing to obvious inside the code but now the key is also exposed,so what i can do ?
Many guys say about flutter_secure_storage and .env but are they really secure on client side?
Here is my code :
Future<String> decryptMessage(String token) async {
  try {
    token = token.replaceAll('"', '');
    print('Encrypted token from decryptMessage function: $token');

    //Key
    var iv = encrypt.IV.fromUtf8('ASDFGHJKLASDFGHJ');
    var key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8('ASDFGHJKLASDFGHJ');
    final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(
      key,
      mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc,
      padding: null,
    ));

    // Decrypt
    var encryptedToken = encrypt.Encrypted.fromBase64(token);
    final decryptedToken = encrypter.decrypt(encryptedToken, iv: iv);

    print(decryptedToken);
    return decryptedToken;
  } catch (error) {
    throw Exception('Error occurred: $error');
  }
}


Please describe your use case. Are you in control of the "client side"? Why do you need to decrypt the token client side? Generally the client obtains the token from a trusted service (maybe the server itself) and it then presents it to the server from which it consumes the service the client is after.

Im using mapbox(like google maps api ) for my mobile app where i use the token inside the url and then in client side , im kinda confused of how i can make it more securly as im a beginner with all of that .  I thought to use server api in order to encrypt it and send it back in the client but i fell on trap where i maybe protected my token but now my decrypt key is also exposed .

I'm not getting the use case. Instead of a token this seems to be some kind of transport security that is being implemented. That's not how tokens work and the shown protocol is not secure for that. But hey, it could well be that I'm misunderstanding what is happening with this particular service.

Its a service that its actually serving a map , im trying to avoid to do that in my own server because i need a lot of hardware ... and i mean A LOT(if i serve my own map). . So im trying to protect the token because i will be charged a lot also if someone elses use it  , its a SaaS actually . I dont know if i make it easier or not :P .When i hit the url of the map in postman its giving me unauthorized also so i have no clue what it must return as an answer and how i will pass all of that data in a mobile app.

This is a tricky situation if you don't control the client side. Having the client connect to your service and having acting that as proxy seems the logical way to go.
